# Type mismatch: cannot convert from Son to Super

Tags: java, object, types, abstract-class, hierarchy

I'm making a Stratego game in java and I'm having a problem with one of the game pieces, which throws me the error:

> "Type mismatch: cannot convert from General to Piece"

I have all other pieces such as bomb scout, Marshall etc.. all defined and properly working, however, this gGeneral is giving me that error and I can't seem to understand why because when I wrote the code, I literally copy pasted from the other pieces and changed only its value(integer value of a piece to use in combat purposes) and its icon.

this is a sample code from one of the Pieces:

```
package Strategu.Pecas;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;

import Strategu.Piece;

public class Major extends Piece {
public ImageIcon imageRed = new ImageIcon(
        "D:\\faculdade\\Modelação e Programação\\code\\MOP\\src\\Strategu\\Gallery\\red\\Major.png");
public ImageIcon imageBlue = new ImageIcon(
        "D:\\faculdade\\Modelação e Programação\\code\\MOP\\src\\Strategu\\Gallery\\blue\\Major.png");
ImageIcon image = null;
int value;
public String nome;
public int cx;
public int cy;

public Major(int alliance) {
    super(alliance, Cx, Cy);
    this.value = 7;
    if (alliance == 0)
        image = imageRed;
    if (alliance == 1)
        image = imageBlue;
    this.nome = "Major";

}

@Override
public String getNome() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return nome;
}

@Override
public boolean canMoveTo(int x, int y) {// movimento basico de todas as unidades expto o scout
    if ((x == Piece.Cx + 1 & y == Piece.Cy) | (x == Piece.Cx & y == Piece.Cy + 1)
            | (x == Piece.Cx - 1 & y == Piece.Cy) | (x == Piece.Cx & y == Piece.Cy - 1)) {
        return true;
    } else {
        System.out.println("movimento invalido");
    }
    return false;
}

@Override
public ImageIcon getIcon() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return image;
}

@Override
public int getValue() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return value;
}
}
```

and this is the General piece that I don't know why is giving me so much trouble with a type mismatch error

```
package Strategu.Pecas;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;

import Strategu.Piece;

public class General extends Piece {
public ImageIcon imageRed = new ImageIcon(
        "D:\\faculdade\\Modelação e Programação\\code\\MOP\\src\\Strategu\\Gallery\\red\\General.png");
public ImageIcon imageBlue = new ImageIcon(
        "D:\\faculdade\\Modelação e Programação\\code\\MOP\\src\\Strategu\\Gallery\\blue\\General.png");
ImageIcon image = null;
int value;
public String nome;
public int cx;
public int cy;

public General(int alliance) {
    super(alliance, Cx, Cy);
    this.value = 9;
    if (alliance == 0)
        image = imageRed;
    if (alliance == 1)
        image = imageBlue;
    this.nome = "General";

}

@Override
public String getNome() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return nome;
}

@Override
public boolean canMoveTo(int x, int y) {// movimento basico de todas as unidades expto o scout
    if ((x == Piece.Cx + 1 & y == Piece.Cy) | (x == Piece.Cx & y == Piece.Cy + 1)
            | (x == Piece.Cx - 1 & y == Piece.Cy) | (x == Piece.Cx & y == Piece.Cy - 1)) {
        return true;
    } else {
        System.out.println("movimento invalido");
    }
    return false;
}

@Override
public ImageIcon getIcon() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return image;
}

@Override
public int getValue() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return value;
}
}
```

also I'm putting here the abstract class of the piece:

```
package Strategu;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

import Strategu.Place.Spot;
import Strategu.board;

public abstract class Piece {

protected final int alliance; // 0 é vermelho 1 é azul

public static int Cx;
public static int Cy;

protected Piece(int alliance, int x, int y) {
    this.alliance = alliance;
    this.Cx = x;
    this.Cy = y;

}

public void setPieceAtPlace(Place p) {
    Piece peça = this;
    int x = p.coordinateX;
    int y = p.coordinateY;
    if (p instanceof Spot) {
        board.tab[x][y] = new Place.Spot(x, y, peça);
        System.out.println("piece adicionada");

    }

}

public void setCxCy(int n, int y) {
    this.Cx = n;
    this.Cy = y;
}

public void sendToGrave(Piece p) {
    if (p.alliance == 1) {
        Graveyard.sendToGrave(p);
    } else {
        Graveyard.sendToGrave(p);
    }
}

public abstract String getNome();

public abstract boolean canMoveTo(int x, int y);

// public abstract Piece moveTo();
public abstract ImageIcon getIcon();

public abstract int getValue();

public String toString() {
    String Ali;

    if (this.alliance == 0) {
        Ali = "RED";
    } else {
        Ali = "BLUE";
    }

    return Ali + " " + getNome() + " " + "value:" + getValue() + " x:" + Piece.Cx + "  y:" + Piece.Cy;

}

}
```

Comment: If you are using eclipse sometimes it says cannot convert but the problem actually is you haven't imported all the classes it needs. Check you have imported the General class and the Piece class.

Comment: yes, im using eclipse and the imported  classes that the piece as should not be the problem because the major for example as the same code as the general but it doesnt do the error, so i belive the problem is with eclipse then, is there a way to fix it?

Comment: Code looks fine. Can you try compiling it outside eclipse context once, i.e. I meant using commands in  terminal?

Comment: ill try to run it on intelIJ see if anything changes else i will hand it with a General1 class wich is equal to general exept it works haha